# Cluster Kubernetes - Deploy httpd and access from external

Tags: kubernetes

I created my Kubernetes cluster and I try to deploy this yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: httpd-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: httpd-app
  ports:  
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30020
      name: httpd-port
  type: NodePort
```

This is the configuration:

```
[root@BCA-TST-K8S01 httpd-deploy]# kubectl get all -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/httpd-deployment-57fc687dcc-rggx9   1/1     Running   0          8m51s   10.44.0.1   bcc-tst-docker02   <none>           <none>

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
service/httpd-service   NodePort    10.102.138.175   <none>        8080:30020/TCP   8m51s   app=httpd-app
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          134m    <none>

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES   SELECTOR
deployment.apps/httpd-deployment   1/1     1            1           8m51s   httpd        httpd    app=httpd

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES   SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/httpd-deployment-57fc687dcc   1         1         1       8m51s   httpd        httpd    app=httpd,pod-template-hash=57fc687dcc
```

But I can't connect to the worker or from the cluster IP:

```
curl http://bcc-tst-docker02:30020
curl: (7) Failed to connect to bcc-tst-docker02 port 30020: Connection refused
```

How can I fix the problem?
How can expose the cluster using the internal Matser IP (for example I need to access to the httpd-deploy from the master IP 10.100.170.150 open a browser in the same network)

**UPDATE:**

I modified my yaml file as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd-app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpd-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-service
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 10.100.170.150               **--> IP K8S**
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: httpd-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30020
  selector:
    app: httpd-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And these are the result after I run apply command:

```
[root@K8S01 LoadBalancer]# kubectl get all -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/httpd-deployment-65d64d47c5-72xp4   1/1     Running   0          60s   10.44.0.2   bcc-tst-docker02   <none>           <none>
pod/httpd-deployment-65d64d47c5-fc645   1/1     Running   0          60s   10.36.0.1   bca-tst-docker01   <none>           <none>

NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
service/http-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.236.203   10.100.170.150   8080:30020/TCP   60s   app=httpd-app
service/kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>           443/TCP          13d   <none>

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES   SELECTOR
deployment.apps/httpd-deployment   2/2     2            2           60s   httpd        httpd    app=httpd-app

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES   SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/httpd-deployment-65d64d47c5   2         2         2       60s   httpd        httpd    app=httpd-app,pod-template-hash=65d64d47c5
```

but now when I try to connect to the httpd using K8S IP I receive these error:

```
[root@K8S01 LoadBalancer]# curl http://10.100.170.150:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.100.170.150 port 8080: No route to host
[root@K8S01 LoadBalancer]# curl http://10.100.236.203:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.100.236.203 port 8080: No route to host
```

If I try to connect directly to the node I can connect:

```
[root@K8S01 LoadBalancer]# curl http://bca-tst-docker01:30020
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
[root@K8S01 LoadBalancer]# curl http://bcc-tst-docker02:30020
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: How did you bootstrapped your cluster? Kubeadm? Minikube? What Os are you running?  If I understand correctly you wan to reach out to your httpd service that runs in your cluster from outside using the nodePort?

Comment: How many nodes do you have? I can assume its just one/master? Do you have any firewall in place? Can you check with `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` if the port `30020` is actually open?

Comment: I created my cluster using Kubeadm. The OS is Oracle Linux 8.3, docker version 20.10.5 and Kubernetes version Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"6b1d87acf3c8253c123756b9e61dac642678305f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:10:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}. My scope is to use a LoadBalancer if is it possible. There is a firewall and the range ports 30000-32767 are opened on worker nodes

Answer (score 1):

You're are getting the `connection refused` because the service does not have any endpoints behind it since your label selector is different from the deployment level.

The deployment has `httpd` label while the service is trying to catch all the deployments with  `httpd-app`. Below you can find corrected selector:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: httpd-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: httpd  <-------
  ports:  
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30020
      name: httpd-port
  type: NodePort
```

You can always verify if the service has endpoints. Kubernetes has a great section about debugging services and one of it is called: [Does the Service have any Endpoints?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I can connect directly to the worker nodes, but I can't connect using k8s ip as LoadBalancer.

Comment: But do you have any loadbalancer configured? If yes, what kind? Some cloud one? Metallb?

Comment: No I don't have any LB configured, k8s is the LB as services?

Comment: Please check (this guide)[https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-faq-how-can-i-route-traffic-for-kubernetes-on-bare-metal] about how to route traffic for kubernetes on bare metal. Loadbalancer type is often used in cloud environment where it automatically provision you loadbalancer. With Bare metal you need to use other options such Metallb or just use ingress with ingress controller.

Comment: With the ExternalIP option you provided Kubernetes is no longer responsible for the IP address but you are. So you should use the IP associated with your node's primary interface (e.g. eth0)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have a single container with a web application. now my scope is to deploy in multiple pods, and use an IP (I prefer to use K8S master IP if is it possible) do access to my application, and the system must route the request in a different backend pods, how can perfom them?